# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.omdapi.com": No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android, android-studio, httpconnection

When I try to run my android app, I following error:

```
"java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.omdapi.com": No address associated with hostname".
```

The URL I'm contacting is correct. I have tried restarting wifi on my phone which is connected to the computer when I run my app, I have tried 4G instead of WiFi, and I have tried restarting my computer. But it still shows this long error: http://pastebin.com/LZsc2w45

Do anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Please post error as part of your question not a link. Links can become obsolete.

Comment: Assuming you have internet access and the domain does exist/is registered properly... Have you the declared the internet permission on the manifest?